# Rails 3 auto_link for string values

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

In my Rails 3 app I store a website and a twitter handle for my profile. I'm going to try @Anywhere for the twitter handle, but am not sure how to output the website string as a link.

I looked up auto_link but what if my string is just stored as `example.com` instead of `http://www.example.com`?